# Import Module by StringLiteral

Tags: typescript

The Typescript specification mentions that you can import a module by  `module(StringLiteral)` :

[image: Import by stringliteral]

However it doesn't work for me:

```
module M
{
}
import test1 = M; // Okay 
import test2 = module(M); // Okay 
import test3 = module("M"); // Error
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a string literal, you are telling TypeScript this is an external module.  This would be defined either by another file of that name (i.e. "M.ts") in the folder with top level 'export' statements (which signify it is an external module), or by declaring such external modules exist (e.g. see the "node.d.ts" typing in the Node sample which declares the built in Node modules).

Answer (score 2):

`module M { }` defines an *internal* module, not an *external* module.

`import test1 = module(M);` should be a syntax error per the grammar (`M` is not a string literal).

`module("M")` is an error because there's no *external* module that can be resolved by "M" (see Bill's answer for more on that)